# React Native Image Resizer package receiving null when doing resize on iOS

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm using the package react-native-image-resizer for image resize and optimization. The android platform is working well, but in iOS I'm getting null when calling the function.

I've done already, package re-install, re-link, version-downgrade, deleting node_modules and I don't know what else to do. I'm losing my mind. The codebase works excellent on Android but on iOS doesn't. The package is supposed to work on both platforms.

Ok, so my code pretty much goes like this, just as in the package tutorial:

```
ImageResizer.createResizedImage(data.uri, 800, 600, 'JPEG', 80);
```

Ive deleted the '.then' part of the code to see the yellow debug box on the phone. It prints a null is not an object right in the method call.

data.uri is my path, it prints the following format:

file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/02CF62B9-2372-40E9-BC3B-3CA18C/Library/Caches/Camera/C327A9AC-49A4-A5BF-21313CEC14E4.jpg

I don't really see where the null is.

I just want the issue to go away, I've deleted some lines of code inside the method, expecting this to work, but just with calling the method, it does not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so found the solution which is weird. I created the same project with all global and local dependencies up to date. When I say the same project, I mean the same .js files. That was it, the project now fully works with android and iOS.

Answer (score 0):

The null error is occurring when it evaluates the function `createResizedImage`.

If you've just installed the Resizer package, make sure you have run `pod install` in your `ios` directory, and you need to close and restart the server/simulator otherwise you will see this error.